# Ubuntu Only shows 2.7 GB of ram, I have 4 GB!

Tags: ram, windows-vista

I am new to Ubuntu, I dual booted it with Windows vista 32 Bit, in vista I  Also only show 2.7 GB through internet research,I have concluded that, that was because I had the 32-Bit version of vista. Ubuntu on the other hand is 64-Bit. BIOS knows that I have 4 GB how can I get Ubuntu to learn that fact too?

Comment: How did you check? Try `free -m` in a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about the 64 bit version,skip to the next part.
To check this, open a terminal and type,

```
uname -m
```

If your system is a 64 bit one, it will show 
"x86_64" 
if its 32 bit it might show something like "i686" or similar.

Once you're satisfied with the version,  PLz check if your system uses "Shared Memory" for PCIe (display Adapter). If its configurable, you can free up some from the BIOS so your physical memory will increase. If its not the case(shared memory), another common reason might be PAE.

You can follow the steps in this community guide to enable PAE.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE

Hope this helps.